# How to accomplish this nl to br functionality in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the past, in previous versions of MVC, in the need for one nl to br functionality in Razor Views, I used to implement the following nl to br HTML helper:

```
public static class FormatingHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Nl2Br(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(text);
        else
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            string[] lines = text.Split('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    builder.Append("<br/>");
                builder.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(lines[i]));
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I tried that with `ASP.NET Core MVC` but it didn't work, the `MvcHtmlString` class doesn't exist.

In truth, I think that HTML helpers don't even exist anymore, replaced by tag helpers.

Anyway, how can this `Nl2Br` functionality be implement with `ASP.NET Core MVC`?

Answer (score 4):

HTML helpers still exist, but for this problem TagHelpers are used in ASP.NET Core indeed. You could simply author your own custom TagHelper like for instance:

```
public class Nl2BrTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    //Set this as <nl2br text=
    public string Text { get; set; } 

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";    // Replaces <nl2br> with <div> tag

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            string[] lines = Text.Split('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    builder.Append("<br/>");
                builder.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(lines[i]));
            }
        output.Content.SetContent(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please adjust according to your own needs. More info about authoring your own tag helpers can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to the proposal of Danny van der Kraan with slight changes for ASP.NET Core 1.1

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace AppName.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("nl2br", Attributes = "text")]
    public class Nl2brTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = string.Empty;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            string[] lines = Text.Split('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    builder.Append("<br/>");
                }
                builder.Append(WebUtility.HtmlEncode(lines[i]));
            }

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(builder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```